# How to inspect JSP request URL for String

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following `processor.jsp` file:

```
<%
    response.sendRedirect("http://buzz.example.com");
%>
```

I want to change it so that it inspects the HTTP request URL for the presence of the word "fizz" and, if it exists, redirect the user to `http://fizz.example.org` instead.

So something like:

```
<%
    String reqUrl = request.getURL().toLowerCase();
    String token = null;
    if(reqUrl.contains("fizz")) {
        token = "fizz";
    } else {
        token = "buzz";
    }

    String respUrl = "http://%%%TOKEN%%%.example.com".replace("%%%TOKEN%%%", token);
    response.sendRedirect(respUrl);
%>
```

However this doesn't work. Any ideas on what I should be using instead of `request`, or if I'm doing anything else wrong?

Comment: First: **do not** use JSP for this, use a Servlet Filter.

Comment: Thanks @LuiggiMendoza (+1) - however I **must** use a JSP here. I will spare SO the long backstory, but it absolutely must be done via JSP, trust me.

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is you used a non-existent function `request.getURL()` rather than `request.getRequestURL()`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot trust in the design of someone who uses scriptlets to solve his/her problem.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to avoid *Scriplet* instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) and [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) that is more easy to use and less error prone.

Sample code using JSTL `<c:choose>` that is equivalent to Java `switch` case.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
...

<c:set var="defaultURL" value="xyz"/>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(request.getRequestURI(), 'fizz')}">
        <c:redirect url="http://fizz.example.com" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(request.getRequestURI(), 'buzz')}">
        <c:redirect url="http://buzz.example.com" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:redirect url="http://${defaultURL}.example.com" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Read more about [All Tags | Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) and [Oracle Tutorial - Using JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)